# Chef, installation of nokogiri with system libraries fails on Centos 6.5

Tags: ruby, chef, rubygems

I'm trying to fix a recipe that needs the gems nokogiri and savon on Centos 6.5.

Since the simple

```
chef_gem 'nokogiri'
require 'nokogiri'
chef_gem 'savon'
require 'savon'
```

does not work (chef says that patching libxml2 2.8.0 returned an error),
(Edit: here is the complete error http://pastebin.com/mUZVyZ4H )

I decided to try to install nokogiri with the system libraries.

If I do it directly on the server everything works fine:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install nokogiri -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.6.2.1" -- --use-system-libraries
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
Successfully installed mini_portile-0.6.0
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.2.1
2 gems installed
```

But if I run the installation through Chef with the command:

```
chef_gem "nokogiri" do
  options("-- --use-system-libraries")
  action :install
end
require 'nokogiri'
```

I get an error:

```
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of gem install nokogiri -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.6.2.1" -- --use-system-libraries ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
---- End output of gem install nokogiri -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.6.2.1" -- --use-system-libraries ----
Ran gem install nokogiri -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "1.6.2.1" -- --use-system-libraries returned 1
```

Since the embedded Ruby is 1.9.3

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

My guess is that Chef is using the wrong gem binary (the system Ruby is 1.8.7), but I have no idea why this is happening, especially because the previous `chef_gem 'nokogiri'` seemed to use the right one.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens without `options("-- --use-system-libraries")`?

Comment: I added the link to pastebin above

Comment: Do you have libxml2 and libxslt installed?

Comment: Yes, I do, otherwise it would not even get at that point.